# Question on Brun's theorem on twin primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let
$$
\pi_2(x)=\mbox{card} \{ p \leq x :  p, p+2 \mbox{ are primes }\}
$$
and let $\pi(x)$ be the prime counting function.

Brun showed that
$$
\lim_{x \to  \infty} \frac{\pi_2(x)}{\pi(x)} =0
$$

**Question** Is it known that this limit is zero if $2$ is replaced by another even integer? More previsely, let $n$ be a positive integer and let
$$
\pi_{2n}(x)=\mbox{card} \{ p \leq x :  p, p+2n \mbox{ are primes }\}
$$
Is it true that
$$
\lim_{x \to  \infty} \frac{\pi_{2n}(x)}{\pi(x)} =0 \,.
$$

I know that by Zhang theorem there exist some $n$ such that $\pi_{2n}(x) \to \infty$ but this does not imply that the above limit is not 0.

**P.S.** I am aware that questions like this are typically either well known or extremelly hard to prove, that's why i stated it as "Is it known" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $N$ be some even integer. Then it is known that there exists some constant $A>0$ such that

$$
\#\{p\le x:p,p+N\text{ prime}\}\le{Ax\over\log^2x}\prod_{\substack{p|N\\p>2}}{p-1\over p-2}.
$$

This can be proven using Brun's sieve or Selberg's sieve. A similar inequality holds for Goldbach's problem as well:

$$
\#\{p\le N:p,N-p\text{ prime}\}\le{BN\over\log^2N}\prod_{\substack{p|N\\p>2}}{p-1\over p-2}.
$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  The first inequality trivially implies what I want. Do you have by chance a good reference for this?

Comment: Halberstam & Richert's 1974 book _Sieve Theory_ would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Warning: This is only a partial answer due to using a yet unproven (nor refuted) conjecture. Quite a bit too long to leave as a comment anyway.

If the [first Hardy-Littlewood conjecture for prime $k$-tuples](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-TupleConjecture.html) (here's a post about it on MSE for some added context, as the first link I provided refers to what would be naturally a prime $k$-tuple, a $k$-tuple of primes, as a $(k-1)$-tuple with their notation: [Asymptoptic density of prime k-tuples](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2913295/1104384)) is assumed to be true at least for $2$-tuples, then there would exist a nonzero constant $C_{2n}$ dependent only on $n$ such that :
$$\pi_{2n}(x) \sim C_{2n} \int_{2}^{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(\ln t)^2}$$
Your claim would then be a direct consequence of this and and the result of Brun that you brought up, because up to a nonzero constant the ratio $\displaystyle\frac{\pi_{2n}(x)}{\pi(x)}$ would be equivalent to the same ratio $\displaystyle\frac{\int_{2}^{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(\ln t)^2}}{\int_{2}^{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\ln t}}$ between all other $n$s and $n = 1$ and by Brun you already have the convergence to $0$ for $n = 1$.

Of course you can probably prove that $\displaystyle\frac{\int_{2}^{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(\ln t)^2}}{\int_{2}^{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\ln t}} \xrightarrow[x \to +\infty]{} 0$ without Brun's theorem/lemma/whatever-is-its-name, it's just a nice short way to do this with what was brought up already though.